# ClassCastException with Junit Test Cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to write the Junit Test cases for a Spring Boot Microservice Application where I am facing the ClassCastException.

```
@Mock
Authentication authentication;

@Mock
AuthenticatedUser authUser;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
    authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
}

@Test
@WithMockUser(username="myuser@test.com")
public void postApiSucess()  throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mockMvc.perform(post("/myapi/").content(mapper.writeValueAsString(customEventsTrace))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .with(authentication(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(Test.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
}
```

Now, when it hits the controller and faces the syntax

```
AuthenticatedUser authUser = (AuthenticatedUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                .getPrincipal();
```

It gives the exception as

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.demo.example.AuthenticatedUser
```

whereas AuthenticatedUser implements UserDetetails

```
public class AuthenticatedUser implements UserDetails
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Read it again : `User` cannot be cast to `AuthenticatedUser`, not `UserDetails`

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas comment is “correct” in a Spring application normally a UserDetail object will be returned by the call getPrincipal().

From the spring security part it should be enough to deal with the UserDetail object and not with your application represantion of the User (AuthenticatedUser).

May be following links from Baeldung will help you a little bit: https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Comment: How come it works when I run the application and send the same bearer token?

Comment: Ok that is another Part.
A example code you will find here https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-resource-server-2
And Baeldung Test sample for JWT Baerer Token here https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs and https://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc